# How parse JSON and set as Object Model

Tags: retrofit2, jsonschema2pojo

I have an API with 2 different response:

response OK

```
{ "name": "test" }
```

response KO

```
[
    {
        "name_1": "test",
        "name_2": "test"
    }
]
```

the problem is that using Retrofit, normally, I use a model to parse results but response KO has not an array name.

How can I create a model? (I cannot change the API)

Comment: You can use two different models.

Comment: Using Retrofit can I use 2 different models? Retrofit can accepts only 1 response model...

Comment: Sure. You just need to add your second POJO to the retrofit client as you did with the first one.

Comment: Normally I use

```Call<CLASSMODEL> login(@Body HashMap<String, String> body);```

how can I set 2 models ?

Comment: Are you using Gson to serialize /deserialize your Json data?

Comment: yes, I am using Gson

Answer (score 1):

So to add another POJO you can do this:

```
private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()

 .registerTypeAdapter(Model1.class, new GsonDeserializer<Model1>())


 .registerTypeAdapter(Model2.class, new GsonDeserializer<Model2>())

//or  create a POJO for the names array of Model2
.registerTypeAdapter(Model2.class, new GsonDeserializer<Names>())
```

Where `GsonDeserializer` is a custom serializer that can be defined, like:

```
public class GsonDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {

@Override

public T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

 JsonObject el = json.getAsJsonObject();

 return new Gson().fromJson(el, typeOfT);

}
```

And then in your Retrofit client you just add:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()

.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))

.build();
```